# Do we count only distinct roots in Descartes' rule of signs?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Descartes' rule of signs states that numbet of positive roots of a polynomial $P(x) = a_nx^n + ... + a_1x + a_0$ is not greater than the number of sign changes of coefficients.

By Gauss we know that number of complex roots of $P(x)$ is $n$ and therefore, number of real (in this case positive) roots is certainly $\leq n$ and we can count same roots more than once if $P(x)$ indeed has multiple roots.

Okay, suppose that number of signs changes of $P(x)$ is $k$ and also suppose that we have set $S$ of all positive roots of $P(x), S = \{x_1, x_2, ..., x_m\}, m \leq n$ and some $x_i, x_j$ can be equal. Now, take that same set and eliminate those equal elements (eliminate all $x_i = x_j$ when $i \neq j$), that new set call $S'$ and let's say $|S'| = r.$

Does Descartes' rule of signs tells us that $m$ cannot be greater than $k$ or that $r$ cannot be greater than $k$?

Does this rule counts multiple roots more than once or it counts just disctint roots?
I am asking this because the geometric proof given here https://math.hmc.edu/funfacts/descartes-rule-of-signs/ has sense to me if we count only distinct roots (because that's number of intersections of polynomial with the $x$-axis) but no otherwise. Thanks

I saw in the comments that the rule counts multiple roots (say $x_0$) more than once. Since the proof given in the link is geometric, does polynomial bounces near the crossing point $(x_0, 0)$?

How exatcly the number of $x_0$'s we counted reflect on the behaviour of $P(x)$ near that point? ($)

My hypothesis is that if that number is even polynomial has parabolic shape near that point and if it is odd polynomial has shape simillar to the curve $x^3$ (and since the parity of sign changes and positive roots (counted with multiplicity) are equal, then this does not change number of ups and downs of our curve - now proof has sense but please answer #)

Comment: Descartes' rule of signs will be counting the roots according to their multiplicity (so counts multiple roots more than once). See e.g. the Wikipedia example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs#Example:_real_roots.

Comment: Well then I don't understand the proof given in the link. Suppose $P(x)$ has two positive roots, $x_i, x_j$ such that $X = x_i = x_j, i \neq j.$ Will that polynomial "bounce" around the point $(X, 0)$ (bounce = slopes right before and after point $(X, 0)$ has different signs and curve is obviously continuous) and what if $P(x)$ has 3 or 4 or 5 multiple roots, how that reflect behaviour of curve near the point $(X, 0)$?

Comment: $x^2-2x+1$ has two sign changes, and one double positive root.  So we must count with multiplicity.

Comment: @GEdgar I don't understand your conclusion... If we count root $x = 1$ once then number of positive roots (1) is less or equal than the number of sign changes (2) which is true because $1 \leq 2.$ But same holds if we count $x = 1$ twice because $2 \leq 2.$

Comment: $x^2-2x+1$ has two sign changes.  Descartes' rule of signs therefore tells us: the number of positive roots is either $0$ or $2$.  That works only if we count the double root $1$ as two roots.

Comment: Wait, I tought Descartes rule tells us that number of positive roots is *equal or less* then $2$ not that it is $0$ *or* $2$.

Comment: If $m$ is the number of sign changes, then Descartes' rule tells us that the number of positive roots is at most $m$, and if less than $m$ it is less by an even amount.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Can you please answer additional question I wrote (about bouncing)?

Comment: I think I got it. It's just derivative of $(x + \alpha)^nR(x).$ We know $f(x) = (x + \alpha)^n = n(x + \alpha)^{n - 1}.$ So, positivity of slope in $f(x)$ depends on the sign of $f'(x).$ We know shapes of any $(x + \alpha)^2, (x + \alpha)^3.$ Therefore, by the obvious induction we get that slopes of $g = (x + \alpha)^4$ are changing as values of $(x + \alpha)^3$ and that is $-, 0, +$ so slopes of $g = (x + \alpha)^4$ are going $-, 0, +$ or simply $g$ is decreasing, then slope is 0 (at $x = -\alpha$) and than increasing, which gives it U shape. And from this simillary for $(x + \alpha)^5,$ etc.

Comment: Of course, I meant $f' = ((x + \alpha)^n)' = n(x + \alpha)^{n - 1}.$

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is a root with multiplicity $m$, then $f(x)= (x-X)^m$ divides $p(x)$, so $p(x)=f(x) q(x)$ for some polynomial $q(x)$ where $q(X)\ne0$. Note that because $q(X)$ is (continuous) polynomial with $P(X)\ne0$, there is some small interval $[X_-,X_+]$ not containing $0$ (where $X_-<X<X_+$) on which $q(x)\ne0$ and does not change sign.

If $m$ is even, $f(X_-)$ and $f(X_+)$ are both positive (they are both even powers of a nonzero number), and therefore $p(X_-)$ and $p(X_+)$ have the same sign as $q(X)$. If $m$ is odd, $f(X_-)>0$ and $f(X_+)<0$ so $p(X_-)$ and $p(X_+)$ have opposite signs, as they are odd powers of a negative number ($X_--X$) and a positive number ($X_+-X$), respectively.

Therefore when $X$ is a root of $p(x)$ with odd multiplicity, the graph of $p(x)$ crosses over the $x$-axis at $x=X$. When $X$ is a root of $p(x)$ with even multiplicity, the graph of $p(x)$ “bounces” on the $x$-axis at $x=X$.

Comment: It's late here so I will check this tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like two things are interchanged in OP.

$\color{blue}{\text{Descartes rule of signs}}$ is not about the sign of $P(x).$
It is about the $\color{blue}{\text{number of sign changes of coefficients}}$, which are ordered accordingly to the powers of $x.$
In the present exercise, the coefficients are $$\underbrace{1}_+,\underbrace{7}_+,\underbrace{-4}_-,\underbrace{-1}_-,\underbrace{-7}_-.$$ Sign change appears only once, it is between $7$ and $-4.$ Therefore, $P(x)$ has exactly one positive root.

As for eventual negative roots, we count the sign changes between coefficients of the polynomial $P(-x).$ The coefficients are $1,-7,-4,1,-7.$ This time, three changes appear. Therefore, our polynomial $P(x)$ has three roots with negative real part. They can be all real, or one real and a pair of complex conjugate roots.

---

As for your additional question:

Example
Consider $P(x)=x^2-2x+1.$ Here are two sign changes. Accordingly to Descartes rule of signs, the polynomial has two roots with positive real part. These roots can be both positive (equal or not), or it is a pair of complexe conjugate roots. Descartes rule says nothing more.
Since it is a quadratic polynomial, $P(x)$ has no other roots.

The same answer (by Descartes rule) would be given for the polynomials $x^2-2x+4$ or $x^2-2x+\frac{1}{2},$ in general, for $x^2-2x+c$ with $c>0.$
Therefore, the geometric interpretation that you try to associate to the polynomial, is not related to the Descartes rule of signs.

Comment: Please check the link I gave there. If we have polynomial that has at least one multiple ($k \geq 2$ times for example) root, say $x = r$ then we can write $P(x) = x^kR(x)$ where $R(x)$ is also a polynomial. Also, denote by $p$ curve given by $P(x)$ and with $n$ number of intersections of $p$ with x-axis. Now, if $k \equiv 0 \pmod 2$ then $p$ is behaving at point $(r, 0)$ almost like parabola ("U" shape) and thus parity of $n$ does not change, simillary if $k \equiv 1 \pmod 2,$ then $p$ is behaving at $(r, 0)$ simillary as $x^3$ is behaving at $(0, 0)$ and parity of $n$ again does not change

Comment: Did you give the link you aimed to give?

Comment: Please see my question

Answer (score 0):

The [explanation of Descartes' rule of signs that you linked to](https://math.hmc.edu/funfacts/descartes-rule-of-signs/) clearly counts multiple roots and not just distinct roots, since one of the things it says is:

> Moreover, the number of roots (**counted with multiplicity**) must also be even, since p(x) is also positive for very large x, so the graph of p(x) can only cross the x-axis an even number of times.

(I added emphasis to three words, but those are exactly the words on the page.)

The rest of the proof is a little vague about how to treat roots with even multiplicity, however, and that may be the source of confusion.
For example, we have this part of the argument,

> But p'(x) is a polynomial with zeroes between each of the roots of p(x) [why?],

which does not say enough about any multiple root. For example, if $p(x) = 0$ has two roots at one value of $x$ (a multiple root), is there a zero of $p'(x)$ "between" those roots? And does the multiplicity of the zero matter?

For example, consider $p(x) = x^2 - 2x + 1 = 0$, which has a double root at $x = 1.$
Yes, $p'(x) = 2x - 2 = 0$ also has a root at $x = 1$, but in what sense is that "between" the roots of $p(x)$?
Or consider $q(x) = x^3 - 3x^2 + 3x - 1 = 0,$ which has a triple root at $x = 1.$
Again, the only roots of $p'(x) = 3x^2 - 6x + 3 = 0$ are at $x = 1$,
which is not "between" anything, and how do we use the fact that the root of $p'(x)=0$ is a double root?
Or consider $r(x) = x^4 - 4x^3 + 6x^2 - 4x + 1 = 0,$ with a quadruple root at $x = 1$,
for which $r'(x) = 0$ has a triple root at the same point, not really "between" any roots or $r(x) = 0.$

I think this is a flaw in the argument on that page.
To complete the argument, we should say that $p'(x) = 0$ has a positive root between any two *distinct* positive roots of $p(x) = 0,$
and $p'(x) = 0$ has a positive root of multiplicity $n - 1$ at the same value of $x$ as any positive root of $p(x) = 0$ of multiplicity $n > 1.$
When the roots of $p'(x) = 0$ at the multiple roots of $p(x)=0$ are counted correctly then the roots of $p(x)=0$ will be counted correctly.